# Rails editing params in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating an API in Rails and need to adjust the default params (`:id`) multiple times for multiple different methods. I need to do this in the `routes.rb` file, too.

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :inventories, except: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy], param: :sku do
      collection do
        post :upload
        get :buyable_inv
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I have now, but `:upload` actually needs the default `:id` param.

What do I do so that the param for `upload` stays `:id`, and becomes `:sku` for `buyable_inv`?

The `upload` method just uploads a .csv, and the `buyable_inv` method returns a list of everything in the inventory you can buy based on the `sku` input in the request.

Comment: You will need to be a bit more specific or this question will get closed quickly. Please explain as concisely as possible what your intentions and expectations are.

Comment: Can't you just use `params[:sku]` in the upload-action? Or, if needed, set that in the controller yourself?

Comment: Where would I put it in the upload action? because i have tried that and cant get it to work, but there is a good chance I'm not doing it right, very new to rails.

Comment: Please show us your attempt to use it in the upload action, and we can then debug it for you :) it's ok if it's not working - it'll give us an idea of what you are attempting and we can fix the bits that don't work. but a verbal description is not enough to go on.